# vim change instances of same identifier after `ciw`

Tags: register

I'm trying to make it easier to refactor stuff by running a single command that "performs the last rename interactively".

I have a binding for doing this that sort of works, but I'm curious whether there's a way to prevent it from ever getting "out of sync" by replacing an old substitution with a recent edit.

---

so far the best I've been able to find is this, which clobbers a register and a marker and the user to manually "wrap" commands so that they populate the contents of the `p` register. It's also very easy for `<leader>,` to pick up a new edit and there's absolutely no indication that this has happened.

```
nnoremap ciw mP"pyiw`Pciw

nnoremap <silent> <leader>, :%s/<c-r>p/<c-r>./gc<cr>
```

---

I'd like to be able to start with a file that looks like this:

```
AAAA       (instant 1)
AAAA
AAAA
AAAA
```

run the following commands `gg0ciwBBBBBBB<esc>`, get the following buffer

```
BBBBBBB    (instant 2)
AAAA
AAAA
AAAA
```

since `ciw` has been remapped, running `<leader>,` causes the buffer to look like this

```
BBBBBBB    (instant 3)
BBBBBBB
BBBBBBB
BBBBBBB
```

This is correct behavior. If, however, I performed I inserted and then deleted some text after `(instant 2)`. By performing `0ia<esc>` and then `x`

```
aBBBBBBB    (instant 2.1 -- alternate)
AAAA
AAAA
AAAA

BBBBBBB     (instant 2.2 -- alternate)
AAAA
AAAA
AAAA
```

then performing `<leader>,` will result in the following buffer

```
BBBBBBB     (instant 3 -- alternate)
a
a
a
```

the correct identifier `AAAA` was targeted, but the contents of the `.` register has changed. I'd like a solution where performing a mismatched substitution is simply impossible.

Comment: What about a mapping like `nnoremap {key} :%s/<c-r><c-w>//gc<left><left><left>`? maybe add `<c-f>` to bring up the command-line window? Would that be sufficient?

Comment: The thing I'm trying to do is repeat a pseudo-substitution performed by `ciw` + entering text as an action that targets the substituted text. Ideally what I'd like to do is set up `ciw` in such a way that the subsequent edit is stored in a particular register (say `o`) so `p` and `o` are always in sync.

Comment: You provided example of what happens. You also need to provide examples of what you *want* to happen.

Comment: @Klaus ... what happens is what I want to happen. It's just that the way that I implemented it is not robust since it will apply whatever text was inserted last and it's inappropriate for a plugin because it claims at least one register. I added an example showing my partial solution's drawbacks.

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. But I don't understand what you actually want to do. As far as I can understand, you want to change all instances of a word. Oh I get it, you used the term refactoring. Like you already have a source file with a variable name which you want to change, but change for the whole file. But you don't want to do it with a single `:%s` substitution. In other words, you want to make it interactive. I'm guessing you are writing a plugin. I don't have any idea though. You should look at established plugins that use this type of features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `InsertLeave` to capture `@@` and `@.` then use those values in your substitution mapping.

```
nnoremap <expr> ciw <SID>replacer()
nnoremap gs :<c-u>%s/<c-r>=get(g:, 'replacer_pat')<cr>/<c-r>=get(g:, 'replacer_str')<cr>/gc

function s:replacer()
  augroup replacer
    autocmd!
    autocmd InsertLeave * execute "autocmd! replacer" |
          \ let [g:replacer_pat, g:replacer_str] = [getreg(v:register), @.]
  augroup END
  return 'ciw'
endfunction
```

Note: `InsertLeave` will not fire if you use `<c-c>`. It might also act incorrectly when using `<c-o>`.

Answer (score 1):

I recently added this little snippet to my vimrc, which accomplishes a similar but different effect:

```
nnoremap <Leader>cw :let @/=expand('<cword>')<CR>cgn
```

With this, I can do `<Leader>cw`, insert some text, and use `n` to go to instances of the old name and `.` to instantly change the next one wherever it is (see `:help gn`). This provides me with a selective renaming tool.